# App is being closed while screen off while having foreground service

Tags: android, alarmmanager, foreground-service

This is a tricky problem. I have an app that collects GPS data in background (with a foreground service). Also, I set 3 alarms that should run in a frame of hours. All of this is made while having an MDM installed in the device (SOTI, if it's of any help).

Well, when the app is in foreground there's no problem, the GPS data is collected right and the alarms fire up when they have to.
The problem is when I lock the device or the screen goes off. Normally, it will collect some more gps data and in a matter of minutes the app and the foreground service will be killed, no matter what.

The device is definitely not in need of resources as it's the only app that is allowed by MDM, and there's no error as I have crashlytics implemented and it's not giving anything.

For reference, as I can't post much code I start the foreground service as intended (with startForegroundService) and I call startForeground in the onCreate() method of the service. Also I have a wakelock in the service, but this hasn't helped at all.

The alarms are set with alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startDate, period, pendingIntent), but when the app is in background they don't fire. When I start the app again they're reset and they fire.

Any clue of why is my app being killed? The device in which I'm using is a Huawei Y6, if it's of any help. I've already checked https://dontkillmyapp.com/ and made all the things I could to try to not get my app killed, but I failed. Also I've checked the foreground service dumping the info of the phone and the service is marked as foreground service as it should, with a priority number 4 (the time I checked) so it shouldn't be killed...

Answer (score 0):

You need a broadcast receiver when the state goes to onStop to start again the service.
Here is an nice tutorial for that  [enter link description here](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android)

[Never ending service](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response, I already tried that but with no luck :( App gets killed anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a service I'm using for some GPS tracking. The important thing for a service to keep running is a notification bound to it. From what I know about the notification is to make the user is aware of a service running in the background.

In the start command create a sticky notification with the highest priority.

Hope Kotlin code is fine:

```
class TrackService : Service(), LocationListener {

    private val tag = TrackService::class.java.simpleName

    companion object {
        private const val ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID = 3947
        const val FLAG_TICKET_RUNNING = 1
    }

    private var locationManager: LocationManager? = null
    private lateinit var notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder


    /**
     * Start command of service. Contains all starting commands needed to start the tracking
     *
     * @param intent used to call startService
     * @param flags flags used for service
     * @param startId id of service
     * @return type of service, in our case STICKY
     */
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        event = intent!!.getParcelableExtra("event")
        course = intent.getParcelableExtra("course")

        notificationBuilder = createNotificationBuilder()
        showNotification()

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT
    }


    /**
     * Called when service is being stopped. This is where we stop all listeners and set the status
     * to "offline"
     */
    override fun onDestroy() {
        dismissNotification()

        super.onDestroy()
    }


    /**
     * Not needed for our use case
     * @param intent Intent
     * @return null
     */
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? = null


    /**
     * Shows the notification that makes the service more STICKY
     */
    private fun showNotification() {
        if (App.showNotificationContent())
            notificationBuilder.setContentText("Time: - | Distance: -")
        startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
    }


    /**
     * Generates the notification to be shown
     *
     * @return NotificationCompat.Builder
     */

    private fun createNotificationBuilder(): NotificationCompat.Builder {
        if (pendingIntent == null) {
            val notificationIntent = Intent(this, DashboardActivity::class.java)
            notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
            notificationIntent.putExtra("ticket_flag", FLAG_TICKET_RUNNING)
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel("channel-4", "Tracking Channel 4", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)
                val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
                notificationChannel.setSound(null, null)
            }
        }

        return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel-4")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_orienteering)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
                .setContentTitle(event.name + " - " + course.name)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setSound(null)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
    }


    /**
     * This is the method that can be called to update the Notification
     */
    private fun updateNotification(time: String, distance: String) {
        if (App.showNotificationContent()) {
            notificationBuilder.setContentText("Time: $time | Distance: $distance")
            val mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            mNotificationManager.notify(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
        }
    }


    /**
     * Dismisses the notification
     */
    private fun dismissNotification() {
        stopForeground(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the code, I have it more or less like you, but I changed priority of my notification channel and added the setongoing, I'll see if it works like this... Thank you again!

Comment: @misterpresid any positive result?